# Set Environment variables in gradle-pitest-plugin

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gradle-plugin, pitest

Have a project that builds successfully and will pass all tests, except when running pitest.

`build.gradle` is setup to have some environment variables configured in `ext`.  On `bootRun` or `test` tasks those environment variables are set.  However, `pitest` does not have a property of environment variables that can be set like the former does.  Looking for a way to set the information needed so the tests will run successfully as part of pitest.  Without the variables the tests don't have the correct context and fail.

```
using `info.solidsoft.gradle.pitest:gradle-pitest-plugin:1.3.0`

ext {

    setEnvironmentVariables = { environment ->
        environment.put('MAJOR_VERSION', cfg.MAJOR_VERSION)
        environment.put('CONTEXT_ROOT', cfg.CONTEXT_ROOT)
        environment.put('PROJECT_NAME', cfg.PROJECT_NAME)
        environment.put('PROJECT_DESCRIPTION', cfg.PROJECT_DESCRIPTION)
    }
}

bootRun {
    setEnvironmentVariables(environment)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pitest is a JavaExec type task in grade.
So environment variables can be set in build.gradle as:

```
tasks.withType(org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec) {
    environment(String name, Object value)
}
```

Like if you want to set spring active profiles to 'ci' then set it as below:

```
tasks.withType(org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec) {
    environment('spring.profiles.active', 'ci')
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sudhanshu Singsih